# How does Kafka handles producers when all brokers go down?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

While studying and testing Kafka, a doubt came up:

How does Kafka handles **production of records** when **everything is down**?

I know that **Consumers** have a **timeout on polls**, and it will keep polling from time to time for new records, **until Kafka is back online**.

I also know that **Producers** have a queue that's added to. This is the **queue that pushes content to kafka**, but what happens if the entire Kafka cluster is down?

For obvious reasons, the Kafka cluster no longer receives records, but how does that happen client side?

Using **Kafka for Spring**, is there any mechanism that handles this?

Comment: as per my understanding if its down, nothing goes in nor out

Comment: That's what I think too, but how does the client handle it? The intention is to know what will happen, so the entire system is prepared for that, and doesn't explode together with kafka

Comment: it depends on how its down, if socket still open then client hangs(i.e waiting for response) until timeout if any (timeout exception). if socket is not open , u'll end up getting no connection (no connection exception)

Comment: Maybe this can help: [handling-broker-down-in-kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900515/handling-broker-down-in-kafka)

Answer (score 0):

If all Kafka broker is down then there is no data processing. Your data stream is lost. I assume it would be rare to have all nodes crash at the same time given you had 3 or more Kafka brokers.

If any one node is down, then DevOps job should catch that and try to restart it. If restart is unsuccessful then it should try to spin up a new node and add it to the Kafka cluster. This sort of automation is complex and requires DevOps team to implement and maintain the process.

Answer (score -1):

This is very rare scenario, but still to  address this kind of issues and manage the kafka incoming high throughput Kafka has provided the Mirror Maker tool which helps to have a other copy of the cluster. And if the current cluster is down the producer has to send messages to the mirror maker broker.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27846330